# Java NetBeans pass value to JFrame produces a compilation error

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

There are two jFrames.

1. FirstPage
2. SecondPage

There is a button on `FirstPage`. When user clicks it, I need to open `SecondPage`.

This is the code in `FirstPage`:

```
private void btn_testActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String testName="Damith";
    SecondFrame win1=new SecondFrame(testName);
    win1.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is how I modify `SecondPage`:

```
public SecondFrame(String anyname) {
    initComponents();

}
```

When I run the project it says:

> One or more projects were complied with error

However, when I click "Run Anyway" it works as I expected.

So, why they said "One or more projects were complied with error"?

Comment: Could you also post the compilation error message?

Comment: @toubou It says only "One or more projects were complied with error, Application you are running may end unexpectedly". This error message display as a popup box. That has "Run Anyway" button. When I clicks it program is running as I expected. I don't know why that error comes.

Comment: "*One or more projects were complied with error*" means that there is an error in one of your project files. The program might work until that section of the code is executed, in which case the program will crash. The compiler is probably telling you where said error is.

Comment: If you think it doesn't, post your code, but do try to remove unrelated parts from it.

Comment: @user1803551 You have said that "The compiler is probably telling you where said error is". I can't see anything like that. Compiler does not tell where is error.

Comment: @user1803551 Actually I start a project add two jFrames and add one button to  FirstPage. Then I do only above changes I have mentioned in my question. (I click the button and write above code, Then I goto SecondPage and I add "String anyname" to constructer.)

Comment: Don't you see any red sign on your class name like  this? http://snag.gy/R768K.jpg

Comment: @toubou Thanks. I have that error in SecondPage. My error and what your screenshot is almost same.  Please can I know that what is the reason for it?

Comment: "*My error and what your screenshot is almost same.*" Then the compiler ***is*** telling you where the error is. Now hover over the error sign and it will tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you modified the default constructor that NetBeans generated for you to:

```
public SecondFrame(String anyname) {
    initComponents();

}
```

This means that if you replaced (instead of adding) the above with the default constructor that NetBeans generated for you, you caused a compilation error, as the auto-generated code from NetBeans invokes the default constructor that it generated, not the one that you explicitly created:

```
/* Create and display the form */
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new SecondFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

So, if the above assumption is correct (and it's the only one, one could make, with the details you provided), the following line is the error's cause:

```
new SecondFrame().setVisible(true);
```

**If not, just hover your mouse over the red sign of the exact line on your editor to let the compiler inform you about the specific error.**

Comment: Thanks you very much. It is possible in c# with Visual Studio. So I thought it is possible in java also.

That mean I need to override the constructor if need to pass a value? Is that a right way?

Comment: No, there is no constructor overriding concept in Java (you need to make clear the difference between overriding and overloading first). Instead, there is a "multiple constructors" concept, according to which you could have the default one, that NetBeans provided you with,for example and also add a constructor that takes an argument, just like you did. On runtime, the JVM is pretty clever enough to decide which one is invoked, according to what you specified in you code, also.

Comment: Than you very much :-)